# What does trait Name[+Something] mean in scala

Tags: scala

I was reading through the scala default library code and found this piece:

```
trait TraversableLike[+A, +Repr] extends Any
    with HasNewBuilder[A, Repr]
    with FilterMonadic[A, Repr]
    with TraversableOnce[A]
    with GenTraversableLike[A, Repr]
    with Parallelizable[A, ParIterable[A]]
{
    self =>
    ...
}
```

What exactly does that do?

Comment: It means the type parameters `A` and `Repr` are covariant, see https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html#variance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Scala `Generic[TypeParameter]` is a generic type which receives a type as a parameter.

That is `Generic` is like a family of types which can be specialized when a type parameter is provided. A clear example of this is `List` which is the generic type for "lists of things" such as `List[Int]`, the latter being the concrete type "list of integers".

On the other hand, the type modifier "+" before `TypeParameter` is used to determine whether the generic  type is covariant or not. Equally, "-" indicates its contravariance.

[image]

From Martin Ordesky's book (*Programming in Scala*):

[image]

...

...

...

[image]

Finally, `with` mixes your trait with the specified trait.

Comment: Now that is a good answer. Also, that is a really cool feature and good to know it exists.

Comment: @Kilobyte In fact, it is not only a cool feature but an important one. For example, check the trait `Function1` (to represent one parameter functions, http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1 ) it is a generic type with 2 parametric types: One in contravariant position, input value type, and another for return value type in covariant position. This makes sense since the more concrete the return value is the more concrete the is the function itself. Similarly, the less concrete the input value is, the more the function should be.